# Excel - Change format of dates

Tags: excel

I have to change the format of a column that has dates and text into dd/mm/yy. However some of the dates are missing the year so I need to fill up the year but I am not sure how to. How can I only change the format of dates, and add the year component to dates that are missing the year? Thank you :")

Comment: Can you show some examples so it makes it easier for people to help?

Comment: If this isn't a coding question you'd probably be better off over on SuperUser SE

Answer (score -1):

ting-xuan-kelly Please Find The Attach Image

[image: Please See The Screenshot Text Formulas]